# HTML in Dygraph annotation descriptions

Tags: annotations, href, dygraphs

Under the Google charts visualization, there is an "allowHTML" option that allows for placing HTML tags inside annotation descriptions.  Is there something similar in Dygraphs where the annotation allows an `HREF` tag that allows the user to link to another web page?

For example, a stock chart shows a split on a specific date. The annotation, on click, would bring up the press release announcing the split. The description field would be in HTML and include the appropriate `HREF` anchor to the press release.

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that dygraphs doesn't support HTML annotations. However, I think it should be pretty easy to provide this type of functionality by using an additional tooltip library.

Dygraphs relies on the title attribute for the annotations. That is, when you hover over the annotation, the tooltip content is populated from the title attribute on the div. As an aside, you could presumably change which attribute it uses quite easily by editing the dygraph annotation source code. If you use a more comprehensive tooltip library (there are loads of jQuery tooltip libraries out there supporting HTML content), it will supercede the basic browser tooltip that dygraphs uses.

For a basic tooltip library that does the job, you could consider:
http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-content
or
http://qtip2.com/plugins#ajax